# Getting resource not available error while calling rest API

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I am getting this error while calling my rest API after deploying on AWS elastic beans. This was working perfectly on my localhost tomcat server but seems i am missing something in deployment. Index file is running properly on AWS.

[image: Error]

Below are the URLs i am using.

Localhost: **http://localhost:8080/test/rest/transaction/data**

Server: **http://apazonpayuat.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/test/rest/transaction/data**

Please check my code below.

```
@Path("/transaction")
public class TestTransaction {

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/data")
public void preTransaction(TransactionData transaction, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response){
    try {
        String accountId = transaction.getAccountId();
        String idempotenceId = transaction.getIdempotenceId();
        String returnUrl = transaction.getReturnURL();
        long amount = transaction.getAmount();

        System.out.println("Account id: "+accountId);
        System.out.println("idempotenceId : "+idempotenceId);
        System.out.println("returnURL "+returnUrl);
        System.out.println("Amount: "+amount);
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
 see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.pay.paywithcard</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>      
    
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
            
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    </project>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you add a list of dependencies of your application (edit your question)? Which Jersey artifacts do you use and what is their version.

Comment: What Tomcat version are you using and what version does Elastic Beanstalk use? Are you using Jersey 3? This will not work with Tomcat versions earlier than 10

Comment: I am  using jersey 2.7 and tomcat 8 version